# Issue while displaying single pod Pod

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

I am new to Pods CMS and Wordpress.
I am running pods CMS (2.0) and wordpress (3.4.1). I was playing with pods but unable to view single pod page.

I have created few pods like teams etc. I am unable to run view single page of pods.

When I debug, I am getting 404 error in Apache logs. It seems .htaccess issue is there.
This is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What are you naming your Pod Page? And what version of Pods / WP are you running?

Comment: And is your WordPress site in a /wordpress/ folder, and where is this .htaccess file located?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure because I don't know pods but shouldn't `RewriteBase /wordpress/` be `RewriteBase /`

Comment: I have solved it.actully i was not giving the correct pod name.       Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pods is particularly prone to 404s, but usually it's a simple fix. Just visit the permalinks page. In theory just visiting that page should be enough to fix it, but I like to switch permalinks to something else; save, then put permalinks back as they were.

Usually that's enough to solve the issue.

As a side note, you likely don't want to be using "Pods pages" but Pods templates, which can then display the content of your custom post. But let us know how you get on!

Comment: do you mean that the links are cached some how, and disabling/enabling will fix the issue ?

Comment: Don't know if it's cache flush or something else which causes it, but the question comes up all the time on the Pods slack channel. This page from the Pods site describes basically the same thing: https://docs.pods.io/faqs/404-errors-front-end-cpt/